# Undefined value from imported function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Im trying to get a TRUE/FALSE value from another JS "helper" file where I have some functions, however when I try to get the returned value from that function, all I get is "undefined"

```
//firebaseHelper.js
//js file where I have the function that I want to use in my main LoginView.jsx" file

export function isUserLogged(){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user =>{
        if(user){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    })    
}


//LoginView.jsx

import {isUserLogged, signOut} from "../../helpers/firebaseHelper";

class Login extends React.Component {
  state = {
    toDashboard: false,
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(isUserLogged());
  }
```

console.log returns undefined, however when I call for example signOut or isUserLogged and instead of return I add a console.log in those functions I can see the answer in the console.

Comment: `isUserLogged` function has no return value and thats why `undefined` is printed for `console.log(isUserLogged());`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` is asynchronous.

You can do the following:

```
//LoginView.jsx

class Login extends React.Component {
  state = {
    toDashboard: false,
  }


componentDidMount = async () => {
        await firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if (user) {
                ...logged-in
            } else {
                ...logged-out
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: I am very  glad :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: replace your isUserLogged function with:

```
export function isUserLogged(){
    return firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => !!user);
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I tried that but it did not work :( thanks for your time I will use the example that Yossi gave me